# Choosing sub-term after choose term when user post article

Tags: taxonomy-terms

This is my taxonomy, really large. My client want to choose in 2 dropdown menu, first one is parent term, after that, the second menu fetch sub-term which belong to parent term in first menu. How can I do? Is there any module for this case?

> Car
>
> - BMW
>
>   - BMW1
>   - BMW2
>   - BMW3
> - Audi
>
>   - Audi1
>   - Audi2
>   - Audi3
> - Toyota
>
>   - Toyota1
>   - toyota2
>   - toyota3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) is exactly for that purpose.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.
>
> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels through Hierarchical Select!